# Error while launching tendermint node with "tendermint init"

Tags: blockchain, bigchaindb, tendermint

I am launching tendermint with the command "tendermint init" followed by "tendermint node". But it is showing an error message as follows:

```
tendermint node
I[04-06|20:44:11.141] Starting multiAppConn                        module=proxy impl=multiAppConn
I[04-06|20:44:11.141] Starting socketClient                        module=abci-client connection=query impl=socketClient
E[04-06|20:44:11.142] abci.socketClient failed to connect to tcp://localhost:26658.  Retrying... module=abci-client connection=query
E[04-06|20:44:14.143] abci.socketClient failed to connect to tcp://localhost:26658.  Retrying... module=abci-client connection=query
E[04-06|20:44:17.143] abci.socketClient failed to connect to tcp://localhost:26658.  Retrying... module=abci-client connection=query
```

I am not able to figure out where I am making mistake. Please help.

Comment: Check that bigchaindb (application you are using) is up and listening for connections on tcp://localhost:26658.