# How to connect Tendermint node to other instances

Tags: blockchain, tendermint, bigchaindb

I have four VMs, each running BigchainDB and MongoDB inside a Docker container and a Tendermint installation in the VM. I am trying to connect the four instances. When running `tendermint node`, I get several errors that look like this:

```
E[2022-08-07|22:00:29.410] Dialing failed                               module=pex addr=4c9fa2f3c6620c1b96ed2ddfb004b977736f8f76@152.7.177.221:26656 err="dial tcp 152.7.177.221:26656: connect: no route to host" attempts=0
```

When all three of the services (Mongo, Bigchain, Tendermint) are containerized, it does work once I introduce port forwarding, but as-is (which is my specific use case), the nodes cannot seem to find each other. From [this question's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55553529/error-while-launching-tendermint-node-with-tendermint-init), I made sure BigchainDB is listening (inside the container) using `lsof -i :26658`, and this port is forwarded. Following [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60906027/how-to-communicate-multiple-tendermint-abci-instances), I also tried using the `persistent_peers` setting, but that doesn't seem to do it either.

How do I connect these VMs?